# pure css grid with unknown amount of total elements and unknown number of elements in row

Tags: css, layout, element, responsive

Ok so to start with I did searched for this issue first. I may had use wrong query as english is my second language but I did my best to not duplicate.

Ok so let me describe me what I am trying to do. I have an element (lets call it) "A" which contains of plain unordered list of boxes. All boxes are in size that can change because they allign to photo that is inside of them. All  boxes also have margin on the right and on the bottom and are set to float left.

Now problem is that all of those boxes are just plain ul elements. And if element "A" can take entire space 5 of this boxes are perfectly in a row. But framework I am using allows people to put other elements next to element "A" which makes its element decrease own width. So if its decreased enough it can no longer contain 5 boxes but only for. I had solution based on n-th child but it does not work if element is resized.

So my question is how can I create grid that will be justified and always have evenly placed boxes regardless of width of the element that contain them? Also I must do this in CSS only and I cannot modify the structure (It must remain unordered list of divs). Any Ideas? I hope I made myself clear enough:) Thanks.

Comment: Need a code sample (which is a functional CodePen or JS FIddle). Failing that, look into using flexbox, which handles rows quite well and can do limited grid work. Play here: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Comment: If elements are floated and there is not enough space to hold all items, they are wrapped to the next line. Why isn't that working for you? -- We really need a code sample here. *It's like asking a car mechanic to fix your car, but not allowing him to use diagnostic tools or even letting him open the hood. You're just describing him your car.*